# removeWidget() not working

Tags: c++, qt

I am adding widgets and similarly want to remove that widget but the widget is not able to removed from the layout.

```
void mywindow::popUpWindow()
{

    if(stack1->currentIndex()==0){
        mainLayout->removeWidget(stack3);
        mainLayout->addWidget(stack2);
        this->setGeometry(80,50,250,200);

    }

    if(stack1->currentIndex()==1){
        mainLayout->removeWidget(stack2);
        mainLayout->addWidget(stack3);
        this->setGeometry(80,50,250,200);

    }
}
```

I am checking the `currentIndex` of `QStackedWidget` and then adding and removing the widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have one QStackedWidget, put all pages inside of it and use its features to switch between pages instead of having many QStackedWidgets and switching between them manually. If you prefer to have two QStackedWidgets, it's better to create third QStackedWidget, put both QStackedWidgets and switch between them easily. You don't need to manipulate layouts manually.

Anyway, `removeWidget` method only disables geometry management of the widget. It holds the same parent and position as before. You have to hide it manually if you want it to disappear.

Actually, you can just call `stack2->hide(); stack3->show();` and remove layout methods usage. You don't have to remove widget from layout, you can just hide it.